# Angular 11=>12 Material update SCSS

Tags: sass, angular-material

we are upgrading our Angular app from version 11 to 12. Now we are running into an issue with the scss for our themes...

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

@function mat.get-color-from-palette($palette,$hue:default,$opacity:null) {
  @if type-of($hue) == number and $hue >= 0 and $hue <= 1 {
    @return mat.get-color-from-palette($palette, default, $hue);
  }
```

while this worked fine for 11 version 12 throws an error.... :

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "(".
  ╷
3 │ @function mat.get-color-from-palette($palette,$hue:default,$opacity:null) {
  │              ^
  ╵
```

Any idea ?
Best, Peter

Answer (score 1):

We found it. Got fixed :

```
@function mat-get-color-from-palette($palette,$hue:default,$opacity:null) {
```

mat-get vs mat.get